# Atualizar layout a partir de um botão

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

Na tela principal do meu app tem dois botões, uma seta pra direita e outra pra esquerda simbolizando os meses anterior e próximo, neles eu chamo uma intent pra recarregar a página com os valores do mês anterior/próximo, mas não fica legal a tela inteira incluindo a actionbar serem chamadas novamente, gostaria de alguma forma recarregar somente a view/xml. Ja tentei o invalidate(), porém sem sucesso. 
Atualmente meus onclicks dos botões estão assim:

```
 mesProx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                proximoMes();

                Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                getActivity().finish();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);    

            }
        });

        mesAnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                anteriorMes();
                Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                getActivity().finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
            }
        });
```

E essa é a tela principal do app

[image: Tela home]

Método de criação da tela

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        DespesaDAO despesaDAO = new DespesaDAO(getActivity());
        ReceitaDAO receitaDAO = new ReceitaDAO(getActivity());

        GraphView graphView = (GraphView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graph);
        TextView desprog = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDespPrev);
        TextView despesas = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvsomaDesp);
        TextView recprog = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvRecPrev);
        TextView receitas = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSomaRec);
        TextView mesano = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMesAno);
        TextView saldo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSaldo);
        TextView saldoprev = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSaldoPrev);
        TextView acumulado = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvAcumulado);
        TextView nada = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSL);
        ImageButton mesAnt = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btAnt);
        ImageButton mesProx = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btProx);


        Float frcta = receitaDAO.somaReceita(calendar);
        Float frctapg = receitaDAO.somaReceitaRecebido(calendar);
        Float fdspsa = despesaDAO.somaDespesa(calendar);
        Float fdspsapg = despesaDAO.somaDespesaPago(calendar);
        Float sldopg = frcta - fdspsa;
        Float sldo = frctapg - fdspsapg;
        Float maxValue = 0.0F;
        Float minValue = 0.0F;
        Float acmldo = receitaDAO.somaReceitaAcumulado(calendar) - despesaDAO.somaDespesaAcumulado(calendar);
        Float dia1 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("01", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("01", calendar);
        if(dia1 > maxValue)
            maxValue = dia1;
        if(dia1 < minValue)
            minValue = dia1;
        Float dia5 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("05", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("05", calendar);
        if(dia5 > maxValue)
            maxValue = dia5;
        if(dia5 < minValue)
            minValue = dia5;
        Float dia10 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("10", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("10", calendar);
        if(dia10 > maxValue)
            maxValue = dia10;
        if(dia10 < minValue)
            minValue = dia10;
        Float dia15 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("15", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("15", calendar);
        if(dia15 > maxValue)
            maxValue = dia15;
        if(dia15 < minValue)
            minValue = dia15;
        Float dia20 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("20", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("20", calendar);
        if(dia20 > maxValue)
            maxValue = dia20;
        if(dia20 < minValue)
            minValue = dia20;
        Float dia25 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("25", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("25", calendar);
        if(dia25 > maxValue)
            maxValue = dia25;
        if(dia25 < minValue)
            minValue = dia25;
        Float diaMax = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado(String.valueOf(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)), calendar) -
                despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado(String.valueOf(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)), calendar);
        if(diaMax > maxValue)
            maxValue = diaMax;
        if(diaMax < minValue)
            minValue = diaMax;

        final StaticLabelsFormatter labelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graphView);

        if(dia1 == 0 && dia5 == 0 && dia10 == 0 && dia15==0 && dia20 == 0 && dia25==0 && diaMax == 0){
            nada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else
        nada.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        String upperString = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(calendar.getTime()).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(calendar.getTime()).substring(1);
        mesano.setText(upperString + "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(calendar.getTime()));


        labelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[]{"1", "5", "10", "15", "20",
                "25", String.valueOf(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))});
        graphView.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
        graphView.getViewport().setMinY(minValue == 0? minValue : minValue-100 );
        graphView.getViewport().setMaxY(maxValue + 100);


        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{

                new DataPoint(0, Double.parseDouble(dia1.toString())),
                new DataPoint(1, Double.parseDouble(dia5.toString())),
                new DataPoint(2, Double.parseDouble(dia10.toString())),
                new DataPoint(3, Double.parseDouble(dia15.toString())),
                new DataPoint(4, Double.parseDouble(dia20.toString())),
                new DataPoint(5, Double.parseDouble(dia25.toString())),
                new DataPoint(6, Double.parseDouble(diaMax.toString()))
        });
        graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(labelsFormatter);
        series.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.linha_graph));
        graphView.addSeries(series);


        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        desprog.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(fdspsa))));
        despesas.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(fdspsapg))));
        recprog.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(frcta))));
        receitas.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(frctapg))));
        saldo.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(sldopg))));
        saldoprev.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(sldo))));
        acumulado.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(acmldo))));

        mesProx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                proximoMes();

                Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                getActivity().finish();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);

            }
        });

        mesAnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                anteriorMes();
                Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                getActivity().finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Sem saber como a tela é construída/atualizada fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar como um `ViewPager`?

Comment: @ramaral inserido o método

Comment: @sicachester como seria isso, tem algum exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema existe porque você está a colocar toda a lógica da sua aplicação num método cuja função é apenas criar a *View* do *Fragment*.

Sugiro que faça assim:

Declare todas as variáveis que representam os componentes da *View* como atributos do *Fragment*

```
private GraphView graphView;;
private TextView desprog;
private TextView despesas;
private TextView recprog;
private TextView receitas;
private TextView mesano;
private TextView saldo;
private TextView saldoprev;
private TextView acumulado;
private TextView nada;
private ImageButton mesAnt;
private ImageButton mesProx;
```

Defina um método cuja função será preencher esses atributos com dados. Mova o respetivo código, que está no `onCreatView`, para lá:

```
public void populateView(){

    Float frcta = receitaDAO.somaReceita(calendar);
    Float frctapg = receitaDAO.somaReceitaRecebido(calendar);
    Float fdspsa = despesaDAO.somaDespesa(calendar);
    Float fdspsapg = despesaDAO.somaDespesaPago(calendar);
    Float sldopg = frcta - fdspsa;
    Float sldo = frctapg - fdspsapg;
    Float maxValue = 0.0F;
    Float minValue = 0.0F;
    Float acmldo = receitaDAO.somaReceitaAcumulado(calendar) - despesaDAO.somaDespesaAcumulado(calendar);
    Float dia1 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("01", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("01", calendar);
    if(dia1 > maxValue)
        maxValue = dia1;
    if(dia1 < minValue)
        minValue = dia1;
    Float dia5 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("05", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("05", calendar);
    if(dia5 > maxValue)
        maxValue = dia5;
    if(dia5 < minValue)
        minValue = dia5;
    Float dia10 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("10", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("10", calendar);
    if(dia10 > maxValue)
        maxValue = dia10;
    if(dia10 < minValue)
        minValue = dia10;
    Float dia15 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("15", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("15", calendar);
    if(dia15 > maxValue)
        maxValue = dia15;
    if(dia15 < minValue)
        minValue = dia15;
    Float dia20 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("20", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("20", calendar);
    if(dia20 > maxValue)
        maxValue = dia20;
    if(dia20 < minValue)
        minValue = dia20;
    Float dia25 = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("25", calendar) - despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado("25", calendar);
    if(dia25 > maxValue)
        maxValue = dia25;
    if(dia25 < minValue)
        minValue = dia25;
    Float diaMax = receitaDAO.diaUmAcumulado(String.valueOf(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)), calendar) -
            despesaDAO.diaUmAcumulado(String.valueOf(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)), calendar);
    if(diaMax > maxValue)
        maxValue = diaMax;
    if(diaMax < minValue)
        minValue = diaMax;

    final StaticLabelsFormatter labelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graphView);

    if(dia1 == 0 && dia5 == 0 && dia10 == 0 && dia15==0 && dia20 == 0 && dia25==0 && diaMax == 0){
        nada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else
    nada.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    String upperString = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(calendar.getTime()).substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").format(calendar.getTime()).substring(1);
    mesano.setText(upperString + "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(calendar.getTime()));


    labelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[]{"1", "5", "10", "15", "20",
            "25", String.valueOf(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))});
    graphView.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graphView.getViewport().setMinY(minValue == 0? minValue : minValue-100 );
    graphView.getViewport().setMaxY(maxValue + 100);


    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[]{

            new DataPoint(0, Double.parseDouble(dia1.toString())),
            new DataPoint(1, Double.parseDouble(dia5.toString())),
            new DataPoint(2, Double.parseDouble(dia10.toString())),
            new DataPoint(3, Double.parseDouble(dia15.toString())),
            new DataPoint(4, Double.parseDouble(dia20.toString())),
            new DataPoint(5, Double.parseDouble(dia25.toString())),
            new DataPoint(6, Double.parseDouble(diaMax.toString()))
    });
    graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(labelsFormatter);
    series.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.linha_graph));
    graphView.addSeries(series);


    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    desprog.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(fdspsa))));
    despesas.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(fdspsapg))));
    recprog.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(frcta))));
    receitas.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(frctapg))));
    saldo.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(sldopg))));
    saldoprev.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(sldo))));
    acumulado.setText(nf.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(acmldo))));

}
```

No método `onCreateView` ficará apenas o código para inicializar os componentes da *View*, incluindo os `onClickListener`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    graphView = (GraphView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    desprog = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDespPrev);
    despesas = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvsomaDesp);
    recprog = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvRecPrev);
    receitas = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSomaRec);
    mesano = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvMesAno);
    saldo = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSaldo);
    saldoprev = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSaldoPrev);
    acumulado = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvAcumulado);
    nada = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSL);
    mesAnt = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btAnt);
    mesProx = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btProx);

    mesProx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            proximoMes();
            populateView();
        }
    });

    mesAnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            anteriorMes();
            populateView();
        }
    });

    populateView();
    return rootView;
}
```

No método `onClick` chame o método `populateView()`.

O importante aqui é que compreenda que o problema está em querer fazer tudo em apenas um método que tem uma responsabilidade bem definida: criar uma *View*.

Sugiro que reveja o código do método `populateView()` de forma a que a sua responsabilidade seja apenas preencher as *views*, passando a responsabilidade de fazer os cálculos para uma classe, com um método que retorne uma classe com o modelo preenchido.

Comment: muito bom, obrigado pela dica, e se eu quiser fazer aquele movimento de ir pra esquerda ou direita que nem o Evernote faz quando escolho datas, tem como?

Comment: Tem. Pode usar o [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) como foi sugerido num dos comentários à sua pergunta. No entanto terá de ser você a tentar implementá-lo e se tiver alguma dificuldade faça uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Opa, minha sugestão pra te ajudar é criar um método fillActivity(), por exemplo, passando por parâmetro todos os dados necessários para popular os gráficos e demais view. Dentro desse método vc deve carregar todas as views, ai vc pode chama-lo no onCreate e no listener dos botões.

```
mesProx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            proximoMes();
            fillActivity();
        }
    });

    mesAnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            anteriorMes();
            fillActivity();
        }
    });
```

Como já foi comentado, para melhorar a usabilidade dessa tela o ideial seria vc colocar o código dessa activity dentro de fragment e usar ViewPager para gerenciar os meses. Swype para mudar o mês é muito melhor do que apertar num botão. Segue um pequeno guia de como implementar

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html